# trouble setting node['chef-client']['interval']

Tags: attributes, chef-infra

I've searched many places and haven't get found the answer to this, I suspect I'm missing something either fundamental or basic (maybe both)

I'm using  the `chef-client::windows_service` recipe and trying to set the interval and can't seem to sort it out.

I've tried at the role level with:

```
{
  "defaults": {
    "chef_client": {
      "interval":15
    }
  },
  "overrides":{
  }
}
```

and at the node level with:

```
{
  "chef_client": {
    "interval":25
  },
  "tags":[]
}
```

but the interval on the node is still 1800 (default)

Comment: What version of windows?

Comment: I think this is actually a bug. On newer Chef Client versions, the winsw recipe is not included. The winsw recipe is where the interval and service is set.

Comment: windows 7.  sethvargo, thanks for the tip, i'll give that a try!

Answer (score 0):

The interval is set at a default level in the chef-client recipe. You need to override it. Use

```
overrides['chef_client']['interval'] = 900
```

Or

```
override_attributes({
  'chef_client' => {
    'interval' => 900
  },
}),
```

Changed to 900 because you really don't want to run Chef client every 15 seconds. I assumed you meant 15 minutes.